# Arabic text file couldn’t be opened

Tags: swift, string, arabic

I am trying to open `.srt` file using `String`:

```
let str = try String(filePath , encoding : .utf8)
```

But I get this error every time I want to read specific `.srt` file:

> couldn’t be opened using text encoding

[sampleFile](https://cheetateam.ir/2.srt)

what is the problem?

Comment: could not open file using text encoding

Comment: yes i can its a srt file the problem is that the file is not in utf8 how can i convert file to utf8

Comment: @Mamad What language is that?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.  The reason you can't open it is your telling it to use one format when its not.  Do you know what the encodig is?

Comment: @LeoDabus that's supposed to be Swift, but the OP isn't doing it properly. The OP is trying to initialize a string from a file URL/Path not from the contents of the file.

Comment: @Todd I am asking what language is the subtitles

Comment: its arabic the problem is with the file text encoding i should somehow convert file to utf8 file then read it again but i dont know how

Comment: @Mamad UTF8 Supports Arabic. If you didn't create the file using UTF8, then you can't load it as UTF8. The problem is with your file, not the encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often, when you are not sure about the encoding, you can actually request that `init(contentsOfFile:usedEncoding:)` determine the encoding for you during the conversion process, e.g.

```swift
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "2", withExtension: "srt")!
var encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8
do {
    let string = try String(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path, usedEncoding: &encoding)
    print(encoding)
    print(string)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case, it throws an error:

> The file “2.srt” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined.

Needless to say, this obviously is not utf8, much less any other encoding that Foundation understands.

When you look at the file in a hex editor (in this case, in Xcode, right clicking on the file and choose “Open as” » “Hex”), it shows:

[image]

So, we can see that this is text, but the Arabic is not in utf8. And, as https://subtitletools.com/ says,

> Text encoding is a tricky thing. Years ago, there were hundreds of different text encodings in an attempt to support all languages and character sets. Nowadays all these different languages can be encoded in unicode UTF-8, but unfortunately all the files from years ago still exist, and some stubborn countries still use old text encodings. Many devices have trouble displaying text encodings that are not UTF-8, they will display the text as random, unreadable characters.

---

After a little investigation, it would appear that this is a [Windows-1256](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) format. I could not open this on a Mac, but Word on my PC gave me a choice of encodings, and “Arabic (Windows)” looks promising:

[image: Microsoft Word in Windows]

Now, having confirmed the encoding, I would have thought that I could use `CFStringEncodings.windowsArabic` and `CFStringCreateWithBytes`, but I could not get that to work.

So, in the end, I built my own cross reference table:

```
class Windows1256 {
    private static let values: [UInt32] = [
        0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004, 0x0005, 0x0006, 0x0007, 0x0008, 0x0009, 0x000A, 0x000B, 0x000C, 0x000D, 0x000E, 0x000F,
        0x0010, 0x0011, 0x0012, 0x0013, 0x0014, 0x0015, 0x0016, 0x0017, 0x0018, 0x0019, 0x001A, 0x001B, 0x001C, 0x001D, 0x001E, 0x001F,
        0x0020, 0x0021, 0x0022, 0x0023, 0x0024, 0x0025, 0x0026, 0x0027, 0x0028, 0x0029, 0x002A, 0x002B, 0x002C, 0x002D, 0x002E, 0x002F,
        0x0030, 0x0031, 0x0032, 0x0033, 0x0034, 0x0035, 0x0036, 0x0037, 0x0038, 0x0039, 0x003A, 0x003B, 0x003C, 0x003D, 0x003E, 0x003F,
        0x0040, 0x0041, 0x0042, 0x0043, 0x0044, 0x0045, 0x0046, 0x0047, 0x0048, 0x0049, 0x004A, 0x004B, 0x004C, 0x004D, 0x004E, 0x004F,
        0x0050, 0x0051, 0x0052, 0x0053, 0x0054, 0x0055, 0x0056, 0x0057, 0x0058, 0x0059, 0x005A, 0x005B, 0x005C, 0x005D, 0x005E, 0x005F,
        0x0060, 0x0061, 0x0062, 0x0063, 0x0064, 0x0065, 0x0066, 0x0067, 0x0068, 0x0069, 0x006A, 0x006B, 0x006C, 0x006D, 0x006E, 0x006F,
        0x0070, 0x0071, 0x0072, 0x0073, 0x0074, 0x0075, 0x0076, 0x0077, 0x0078, 0x0079, 0x007A, 0x007B, 0x007C, 0x007D, 0x007E, 0x007F,
        0x20AC, 0x067E, 0x201A, 0x0192, 0x201E, 0x2026, 0x2020, 0x2021, 0x02C6, 0x2030, 0x0679, 0x2039, 0x0152, 0x0686, 0x0698, 0x0688,
        0x06AF, 0x2018, 0x2019, 0x201C, 0x201D, 0x2022, 0x2013, 0x2014, 0x06A9, 0x2122, 0x0691, 0x203A, 0x0153, 0x200C, 0x200D, 0x06BA,
        0x00A0, 0x060C, 0x00A2, 0x00A3, 0x00A4, 0x00A5, 0x00A6, 0x00A7, 0x00A8, 0x00A9, 0x06BE, 0x00AB, 0x00AC, 0x00AD, 0x00AE, 0x00AF,
        0x00B0, 0x00B1, 0x00B2, 0x00B3, 0x00B4, 0x00B5, 0x00B6, 0x00B7, 0x00B8, 0x00B9, 0x061B, 0x00BB, 0x00BC, 0x00BD, 0x00BE, 0x061F,
        0x06C1, 0x0621, 0x0622, 0x0623, 0x0624, 0x0625, 0x0626, 0x0627, 0x0628, 0x0629, 0x062A, 0x062B, 0x062C, 0x062D, 0x062E, 0x062F,
        0x0630, 0x0631, 0x0632, 0x0633, 0x0634, 0x0635, 0x0636, 0x00D7, 0x0637, 0x0638, 0x0639, 0x063A, 0x0640, 0x0641, 0x0642, 0x0643,
        0x00E0, 0x0644, 0x00E2, 0x0645, 0x0646, 0x0647, 0x0648, 0x00E7, 0x00E8, 0x00E9, 0x00EA, 0x00EB, 0x0649, 0x064A, 0x00EE, 0x00EF,
        0x064B, 0x064C, 0x064D, 0x064E, 0x00F4, 0x064F, 0x0650, 0x00F7, 0x0651, 0x00F9, 0x0652, 0x00FB, 0x00FC, 0x200E, 0x200F, 0x06D2
    ]

    static let scalars = values.map { Unicode.Scalar($0)! }

    static func convert(_ data: Data) -> String {
        var string = ""
        string.reserveCapacity(data.count)

        for byte in data {
            string += String(scalars[Int(byte)])
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

Then I can convert that

```swift
let string = Windows1256.convert(data)
```

And that yields:

> 1 
> 00:00:00,276 --> 00:00:02,401 
> :انچه گذشت 
> قرباني لين دوهرسته
>
> 2 
> 00:00:02,403 --> 00:00:04,870SW 
> الان ديگه ما دنبال يه مجرم سريالي هستيم

I do not read or write Arabic, so I cannot verify this solution, but it looks promising to my untrained eye.

Needless to say, having done this conversion, you can write this to a file (or convert to a `Data`) using `.utf8` if you need to save the result in this encoding.

Comment: websites like https://subtitletools.com can fix the textfiile i want a way in swift to fix it in place i know the problem is with the textfile

Comment: @Mamad See my attempt at manually converting it, above.

Comment: briliant man! nice ! thats all im looking for . thank you god bless you!